# How to select files to copy as per operating system version in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have built an installer with Inno setup. Recently it was found that some applications do not work in Windows XP. These applications work fine with Windows 7 onward. I need to copy files as per Windows version user is installing on and create program menu shortcuts accordingly. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sections have [`MinVersion` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams&anchor=MinVersion), which you can use to limit a specific section entry to a specific minimal [version of Windows](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes):

```
[Files]
Source: "NeedsWin7.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 6.1

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Needs Win 7"; Filename: "{app}\NeedsWin7.exe"; MinVersion: 6.1
```